# Commands from HUD do not always work in 16.04

Tags: unity, google-chrome, chromium, hud

When I type a command in the HUD and press enter it may not work the first time, so I have to type the command again to make it work. Is anyone else experiencing this in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Is that a problem with all commands you enter there or only some of them? Can you give a few examples you run in there?

Comment: For example if I want to change person in chrome: I may type "matt" and the option "matteo" appears as a suggestion, then I press enter but nothing happens until i try a few times.

Comment: I can only reproduce it in Chromium, but not anywhere else, e.g. in Firefox it works fine. Maybe it's not a fault of the HUD but of Chrome/Chromium?